# 2 macs connected via ethernet

Tags: mac, ethernet, proxy

Ive connected 2 macs via ethernet "connect to server" using this method:

[Send very large files through Ethernet between two Mac computers](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/259569/send-very-large-files-through-ethernet-between-two-mac-computers)

I was able to connect and browse and use all the files on the shared computer, however once I connect to some sites on chrome I get the ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED.

facebook, gmail, instagram all work fine while the macs are connected but a wordpress site and even 2 of my local NYC newspapers give me the ERR.

The second I unplug the ethernet cable from the shared mac, the pages all load.

How can I access both the sever mac files AND avoid the proxy errs.

(the server mac would be using wifi since the ethernet port is used to connect to the host mac) but either on the host or server mac, while plugged in, certain pages get the ERR.

Thanks

Rob

Comment: Do you have a proxy configured?

Comment: Can you post the Ethernet configuration to your question?  Did you configure a gateway for this connection?

Comment: I used these instructions from another thread on this site: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/259569/send-very-large-files-through-ethernet-between-two-mac-computers.  Using an Imac connected via ethernet to a new cheesegrater tower mac. The Imac would be getting the internet via wifi then, and the tower by 2nd ethernet port. On either mac, when just physically plugged in, not even "connected to server" will not load some sites.

Comment: I even tried using a powered switcher: https://www.dell.com/en-us/work/shop/netgear-prosafe-gs105-5port-copper-gigabit-switch/apd/a7042611/networking?gacd=9646510-1025-5761040-266794296-0&dgc=st&&gclid=CjwKCAjwjqT5BRAPEiwAJlBuBfhly0q5DrUqZ4kDqibq2J0dg3bLPwde2yIG_BuRRcjKHOwH-KNBexoCbjEQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds

Comment: If there is another way/suggestion to connect via ethernet other than the way I posted. That could work